# PostgreSQL Call a stored procedure with its name is into variable

Tags: postgresql, procedure, execute

I want to call a stored procedure whose name is in a variable with this code :

```
    DECLARE
      spName text;
      varIn1 text;
      varIn2 text;
      varOut text;
      varSQLQuery text;
    BEGIN
    spName := 'myProc';
    varIn1 := 'Value1';
    varIn2 := 'Value2';
    varSQLQuery := format('CALL myschema.%s(varIn1,varIn2,varOut);',spName,);
    RAISE NOTICE 'varSQLQuery %', varSQLQuery;
    EXECUTE varSQLQuery;
    RAISE NOTICE 'varOut %', varOut;
```

The printed query from varSQLQuery works if I copy and paste them inside the code.
But it doesn't work in EXECUTE function.

The error is : "column "varIn1" does not exist".

I also tried this :

```
varSQLQuery := format('CALL myschema.%s(varIn1,varIn2,varOut);',spName);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE varSQLQuery;

varSQLQuery := format('
  BEGIN
  CALL myschema.%s(varIn1,varIn2,varOut);
  END;'
,spName);
EXECUTE varSQLQuery;

varSQLQuery := format('myschema.%s(varIn1,varIn2,varOut);',spName);
EXECUTE varSQLQuery;

varSQLQuery := format('myschema.%s(varIn1,varIn2,varOut);',spName);
CALL varSQLQuery;
```

I have no more new ideas.

So, how do you call a stored procedure with a name in a variable, with (or without?) the EXECUTE function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I succeeded to get the output variable with the INTO clause in the following code:

```
varSQLQuery := format('CALL myschema.%s($1,$2,$3);', spName);
RAISE NOTICE 'varSQLQuery %', varSQLQuery;
EXECUTE varSQLQuery INTO varOut USING varIn1, varIn2, varOut;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that dynamic SQL does not 'see' the variables as it does not run in the same block context ([documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)). Try to do it like this:

```sql
varSQLQuery := format('CALL myschema.%s($1,$2,$3);', spName);
RAISE NOTICE 'varSQLQuery %', varSQLQuery;
EXECUTE varSQLQuery using varIn1, varIn2, varOut;
```

However the procedure's output parameter will not work as expected. The value of `varOut` will not change. It may be a better idea to use a function instead of a procedure.

Comment: It works and you are right. The output variable is null. Thanks for your help.